# identity not working with inherited table

Tags: postgresql, identity, inherited

I'm using PostgreSQL 11 latest version, having problems with an identity as PK that inherits a table.

assume you have simple parent table like:

```
CREATE TABLE test7 
    (
    id_t7 int GENERATED always AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    folio int GENERATED always AS IDENTITY,
    client int
    );
```

with any inherited table like:

```
CREATE TABLE test7_detail1
(
  --  uuid uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(), <-- fiddle doesn't support it
    in_process boolean,
    id_corte integer,
    ts_captura timestamp(6) without time zone DEFAULT (now())::timestamp without time zone
) INHERITS (test7);
```

if I try insert like:

```
insert into test7_detail1 (client,in_process, id_corte)
values (20797,'t',101)
```

it returns:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "id_t7" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null, 20797, t, 101, 2019-05-03 22:27:54.823894).
```

[here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iYkASiKbr8t1oEg1U2MCcX/2) is the fiddle

what am i doing wrong?
is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I tried `id_t7 serial PRIMARY KEY` instead of `id_t7 int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY` and seems to work.

```
CREATE TABLE test7 (
  id_t7 serial PRIMARY KEY,
  folio serial,
  client int
);

CREATE TABLE test7_detail1 (
  --  uuid uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  in_process boolean,
  id_corte integer,
  ts_captura timestamp(6) without time zone DEFAULT (now())::timestamp without time zone
) INHERITS (test7);

insert into test7_detail1 (client,in_process, id_corte)
values (20797,'t',101);
```

Comment: thanks [acarlstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7231449/acarlstein) **so it's a bug?** identity was declared correctly; was folio incremented?

Comment: I actually test it: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iYkASiKbr8t1oEg1U2MCcX/3

Comment: Using PostgreSQL SERIAL To Create Auto-increment Column: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-serial/

Comment: Well, normally its a good practice that each table has its own auto-increment primary identity index. Depending of the query, it can improve performance and its quite standard. Therefore, I am not surprise that the table don't inherit such column from the parent and that you have to define it yourself.

Comment: on the one hand it's correct being able to solve it by adding an identity to the inherited one but on the other hand I don't understand why it works with sequences (serial) and not with identities that are also sequences? maybe the correct way to work with identities is by making two inserts in a transaction, it doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

identity column is not inherited

From [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)

> If a column in the parent table is an identity column, that property
> is not inherited. A column in the child table can be declared identity
> column if desired.